# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.length') in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
  d3.json("/data/fundraising_vs_analytics_for_2016_candidates.json",
function(data){

   d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text("New paragraph!");

})
</script>
```

I've confirmed that the file `/data/fundraising_vs_analytics_for_2016_candidates.json` exists and the browser can find it.

The file looks like this:

```
[
  {name: "Jeb Bush", count: 10, amount: 120000000},
  {name "Hillary Clinton", count: 13, amount: 67800000}
]
```

However, I get the error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')` in console. I'm not sure how to even begin to trouble shoot this. Any thoughts on things to try? This is my first time I've ever used D3.js.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the `data` parameter to the `data` method instead of the `dataset`?

Comment: Ahh, yes. Let me confirm that that isn't the issue. I thought I had fixed that and by fixing it, this was the second error I got. Thanks.

Comment: @Vohuman good catch, but I must have copied that out of an old buffer, because that change had been made.

Comment: Check the documentation on `d3.json()`: *"the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON."* You are missing the second parameter. Try something like `function(errror, data)`.

Comment: Is this fixed for you? Or still having problems?

Comment: @Alan. No, this is resolved. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the code looks like and resolved the errors:

```
<script>
  d3.json("/data/fundraising_vs_analytics_for_2016_candidates.json",
function(error, data){
if (error) return console.warn(error);

   d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("p")
        .text("New paragraph!");

    })
    </script>
```